# Django: my test migration throws a Key Error but normal migration is fine. What's broken and how do I fix it?

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, migration

Django test migration throws Key Error

I get a Key error, but only when I do `python manage.py test apps/userprofile` and not when I do `python manage.py makemigrations` or `python manage.py migrate`.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

---

```
python manage.py test apps/userprofile
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Got an error creating the test database: database "test_financetracker" already exists

Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_financetracker', or 'no' to cancel: yes
Destroying old test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 23, in run_from_argv
    super().run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 53, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 629, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases(aliases=databases)
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 554, in setup_databases
    self.parallel, **kwargs
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 174, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get('TEST', {}).get('SERIALIZE', True),
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 72, in create_test_db
    run_syncdb=True,
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 148, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 114, in apply
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, project_state)
  File "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 165, in state_forwards
    for name, instance in state.models[app_label, self.model_name_lower].fields:
KeyError: ('hourly_rate', 'hourlyrate')
```

This is the relevant (I think) `hourly_rates` python class from the models.py file:

```
class HourlyRate(TimeStampedModel):
    # TODO remove user PK as it will no longer be used.
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    upload = models.ForeignKey(
        'hourly_rate.Upload', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    timekeeper = models.CharField(verbose_name='Timekeeper ID', max_length=20,
                                  blank=True)  # is required, but blank = True and null = True for backwards compatiblity.
    classification = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CLASSIFICATIONS)
    years_of_experience = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,
                                                      null=True)  # is required, but blank = True and null = True for backwards compatiblity.
    hourly_rate = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    status = models.CharField(choices=UPLOAD_STATUSES,
                              default='requested', max_length=255)
    fiscal_year = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=YEARS, default=2017)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}, {}'.format(self.name, self.timekeeper)

    def status_and_date(self):
        """Return the status and date of the upload, if an upload is available. Else: return status. Might change this later to -"""
        if self.upload:
            return self.upload.status_and_date
        else:
            return self.status  # idea, change to: "-"

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('user__userprofile__name', '-id',)
        verbose_name = 'Timekeeper rate'
```

This is the directory flow, although I removed quite some files for simplicity, so if something is missing, just ask.

```
manage.py
config
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
├── alpha
│   ├── nginx
│   └── supervisor
├── default.conf
├── demo
│   ├── nginx
│   └── supervisor
├── settings
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── base.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── defaults.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── development.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── alpha.py
│   ├── base.py
│   ├── defaults.py
│   ├── demo.py
│   ├── development.py
│   ├── local.py
│   ├── production.py
│   └── staging.py
├── staging
│   ├── nginx
│   └── supervisor
└── wsgi.py
apps
└── report
└── hourly_rate
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── admin.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── apps.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── filters.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── forms.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── helpers.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
    │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
    ├── admin.py
    ├── filters.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── helpers.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   ├── 0002_auto_20170424_1735.py
    │   ├── 0003_auto_20170424_1738.py
    │   ├── 0004_auto_20170424_1818.py
    │   ├── 0005_auto_20170424_1917.py
    │   ├── 0006_auto_20170424_2302.py
    │   ├── 0007_auto_20170504_1948.py
    │   ├── 0008_auto_20170513_1412.py
    │   ├── 0009_auto_20170613_1726.py
    │   ├── 0010_auto_20171115_1051.py
    │   ├── 0011_auto_20180311_1223.py
    │   ├── 0012_auto_20190801_1703.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-37.pyc
    │       ├── 0002_auto_20170424_1735.cpython-37.pyc
    │       ├── 0003_auto_20170424_1738.cpython-37.pyc
    │       ├── 0004_auto_20170424_1818.cpython-37.pyc
    │       ├── 0005_auto_20170424_1917.cpython-37.pyc
    │       ├── 0006_auto_20170424_2302.cpython-37.pyc
    │       ├── 0007_auto_20170504_1948.cpython-37.pyc
    │       ├── 0008_auto_20170513_1412.cpython-37.pyc
    │       ├── 0009_auto_20170613_1726.cpython-37.pyc
    │       ├── 0010_auto_20171115_1051.cpython-37.pyc
    │       ├── 0011_auto_20180311_1223.cpython-37.pyc
    │       ├── 0012_auto_20190801_1703.cpython-37.pyc
    │       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── views.py
```

**Django version is 2.2.9**

Migration files, many automatic ones. Here are the first three of twelve:

**initial**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('customer', '0002_historicalbillingaddress_historicalentity'),
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Upload',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID',
                                        serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(null=True, editable=False)),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(null=True, editable=False)),
                ('excel_file', models.FileField(help_text=b'Kies het door u ingevulde bestand.', upload_to=b'uploads',
                                                verbose_name=b'Upload')),
                ('period', models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)),
                ('status', models.CharField(default=b'upload failed', max_length=255,
                                            choices=[(b'upload failed', b'upload failed'), (b'requested', b'requested'),
                                                     (b'rejected', b'rejected'), (b'approved', b'approved')])),
                ('customer', models.ForeignKey(
                    to='customer.Customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)),
                ('user', models.ForeignKey(verbose_name=b'uploaded by user',
                                           to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

**second, automatic from now on, but this one was edited**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('vendor', '0008_auto_20170417_1656'),
        ('customer', '0002_historicalbillingaddress_historicalentity'),
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('currency', '0001_initial'),
        ('hourly_rate', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='HourlyRate',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(null=True, editable=False)),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(null=True, editable=False)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)),
                ('classification', models.CharField(max_length=20,
                                                    choices=[(b'AS', b'AS'), (b'OC', b'OC'), (b'OT', b'OT'),
                                                             (b'PL', b'PL'), (b'PT', b'PT')])),
                ('hourly_rate', models.PositiveIntegerField()),
                ('status', models.CharField(default=b'approved', max_length=255,
                                            choices=[(b'upload failed', b'upload failed'), (b'requested', b'requested'),
                                                     (b'rejected', b'rejected'), (b'approved', b'approved')])),
                ('period', models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)),
                ('currency', models.ForeignKey(to='currency.Currency', on_delete=models.CASCADE)),
                ('customer', models.ForeignKey(default=1, to='customer.Customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ('user__userprofile__name', '-id'),
            },
        ),
        migrations.AlterModelOptions(
            name='upload',
            options={'ordering': ['-id']},
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='hourlyrate',
            name='upload',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, to='hourly_rate.Upload', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='hourlyrate',
            name='user',
            field=models.OneToOneField(null=True, blank=True, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='hourlyrate',
            name='vendor',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, to='vendor.Vendor', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE),
        ),
    ]

    def apply(self, project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=False):
        return project_state.clone()

    def unapply(self, project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=False):
        return project_state.clone()
```

**second as before the edit**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
from django.conf import settings


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('vendor', '0008_auto_20170417_1656'),
        ('customer', '0002_historicalbillingaddress_historicalentity'),
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('currency', '0001_initial'),
        ('hourly_rate', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='HourlyRate',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('created', models.DateTimeField(null=True, editable=False)),
                ('updated', models.DateTimeField(null=True, editable=False)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)),
                ('classification', models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=[(b'AS', b'AS'), (b'OC', b'OC'), (b'OT', b'OT'), (b'PL', b'PL'), (b'PT', b'PT')])),
                ('hourly_rate', models.PositiveIntegerField()),
                ('status', models.CharField(default=b'approved', max_length=255, choices=[(b'upload failed', b'upload failed'), (b'requested', b'requested'), (b'rejected', b'rejected'), (b'approved', b'approved')])),
                ('period', models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)),
                ('currency', models.ForeignKey(to='currency.Currency')),
                ('customer', models.ForeignKey(default=1, to='customer.Customer')),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ('user__userprofile__name', '-id'),
            },
        ),
        migrations.AlterModelOptions(
            name='upload',
            options={'ordering': ['-id']},
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='hourlyrate',
            name='upload',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, to='hourly_rate.Upload', null=True),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='hourlyrate',
            name='user',
            field=models.OneToOneField(null=True, blank=True, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='hourlyrate',
            name='vendor',
            field=models.ForeignKey(blank=True, to='vendor.Vendor', null=True),
        ),
    ]

    def apply(self, project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=False):
        return project_state.clone()

    def unapply(self, project_state, schema_editor, collect_sql=False):
        return project_state.clone()
```

**third**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('hourly_rate', '0002_auto_20170424_1735'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='hourlyrate',
            name='period',
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='upload',
            name='period',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='hourlyrate',
            name='fiscal_year',
            field=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=2017,
                                              choices=[(2017, 2017), (2018, 2018), (2019, 2019), (2020, 2020),
                                                       (2021, 2021), (2022, 2022), (2023, 2023), (2024, 2024)]),
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='upload',
            name='fiscal_year',
            field=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=2017,
                                              choices=[(2017, 2017), (2018, 2018), (2019, 2019), (2020, 2020),
                                                       (2021, 2021), (2022, 2022), (2023, 2023), (2024, 2024)]),
        ),
    ]
```

[image: debugging on the line it breaks at]

Debugged the line that throws the error.

[image]
Is it the migrations? Is it the code?

Thanks

Comment: and where is your migration file?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question with relevant informations (including the faulty migration file and the test file, and your Django version).

Comment: hi @bruno-desthuilliers, thanks for the feedback. First hurdle - I don't know which migration file is faulty.

Comment: @henko debugging 101: inspect the traceback to try and guess where you can have this information (hint: "/Users/financetracker/myvenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards" looks like a good starting point), edit the relevant file to set a [debugger breakpoint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) there, and check what you have.

Comment: FWIW I don't see anything in your migrations themselves that could cause this issue - they are all generated migrations so you can assume they are correct by themselves. The error itself means that the migrations module cannot find a saved state for the model, which is rather surprising.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers thanks for your debugging advice. What am I looking for at this breakpoint?

Comment: From your screen print it looks like the issue happens with the third migration (it's the only one have `RemoveField` operations) - which was the first info we were looking for. Now I just noticed the two addtionnal methods at the end of your second migration - the overrides of `apply` and `unapply`. Did you add those methods yourself (I mean "you or someone else working on this project")  ??? Those are possibly responsible for you issue one way or another (they should return an updated state).

Comment: Other questions: 1/ what db backend are you using for tests, and 2/ do you have this issue whatever test you run or only on some specific tests or apps ?

Comment: Also, do you use specific settings for tests ???

Comment: Oh and yes: you definitly want to sort this out because a borked migration history is not something you want to keep in your project (future maintenance nightmare garanteed), but in the meantime you can tell django to skip your migrations (at least for this app) when running tests (it will then create the table directly in it's current state). It's a bit of a hack but at least it's a temporary workaround.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers migration 2 has been edited, but not the last two overrides.

Comment: I've NEVER seen such code in a generated migration, and for a good reason: __it actually prevents the migration from being executed__ (as you can see from the traceback and checking [the source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/migration.py#L90).

Comment: to answer your other questions, the backend is PostgreSQL and this is the first test to be written, so it could be a global issue.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers how did the apply and unapply become generated? Should I clean this migration up, which means meddling more?

Comment: "how did the apply and unapply become generated?" => where they, really ? I don't think so, and I see nothing in `django.db.migrations` that would generate this (you may want to have a look [here}(https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/writer.py#L288). `git blame` (or it's equivalent in whatever version control system you're using) might (or not...) tell you more about who last touched those lines, when, and whether the whole file was originally commited in this state or it's been edited.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers stange, it's been there since the first commit. To fix my error, I threw away all the migrations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207188/discussion-between-henko-and-bruno-desthuilliers).